# geom_ribbon: create a rule for colour changes using fill

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like in my `pred_avg` dataset to create a rule (`pred_avg$canopycoverSDmin < pred_avg$covermin`) for color changes using `fill` in `geom_ribbon` using `ggplot2`, but despite my variable `pred_avg$groups` in `fill = groups` is a `factor` doesn't work and I have always `Error: Aesthetics can not vary with a ribbon` as output.

In my example:

```
library(ggplot2)

#Open data set
pred_avg<- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/cc_mean_CI.csv")
str(pred_avg)
#'data.frame':  40323 obs. of  9 variables:
# $ X               : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
# $ DATE            : chr  "2021-06-04" "2021-06-04" "2021-06-04" "2021-06-04" ...
# $ canopycover     : num  47 47 47 47 47 ...
# $ se.cc           : num  1.6 1.57 1.54 1.54 1.54 ...
# $ n.cc            : int  3073 3073 3073 3073 3073 3073 3073 3073 3073 3073 ...
# $ canopycoverSDmax: num  50.2 50.1 50 50 50 ...
# $ canopycoverSDmin: num  43.9 44 44 44 44 ...
# $ covermin        : num  43.1 43.1 43.1 43.1 43.1 ...
# $ covermax        : num  85.2 85.2 85.2 85.2 85.2 ...

# Create the variable (`groups`) for colours changes
pred_avg$groups <- ifelse(pred_avg$canopycoverSDmin < pred_avg$covermin, "A", "H") 
pred_avg$groups <-as.factor(pred_avg$groups)

# Create the plot
         ggplot(pred_avg, aes(x = DATE, y = canopycover, group = 1), fill=factor(groups)) +
         geom_point () +
         geom_line() + 
         geom_ribbon(data=pred_avg, aes(ymin = canopycoverSDmin, ymax = canopycoverSDmax, fill = groups), alpha = 0.1) +
         scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "green"), name="fill") +
         geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = covermin, ymax = covermax), alpha = 0.1) +
         scale_x_date(breaks = "1 week") + 
           theme_bw() + theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                              axis.text=element_text(size=10),
                              axis.title=element_text(size=12),
                              plot.title = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
                              legend.title = element_blank(),
                              axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1),
                              panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))

Error: Aesthetics can not vary with a ribbon
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Please, any help with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify something in the original `ggplot()` it will be inherited by subsequent layers. Don't put `group = 1` up there globally. If you need it for the `line` layer, put `group = 1` just in `geom_line`. Similarly, don't put `fill=factor(groups)` in the base `ggplot()` call because you don't want it being used in the `point` layer, the second `ribbon` layer, etc. You only need it in the first `ribbon` layer, so only put it there. (And you need to put it **inside `aes()`** since it references a column name!)

```
pred_avg$DATE = as.Date(pred_avg$DATE)

# Create the plot
ggplot(pred_avg, aes(x = DATE, y = canopycover)) +
  geom_point () +
  geom_line(group = 1) +
  geom_ribbon(
    data = pred_avg,
    aes(
      ymin = canopycoverSDmin, 
      ymax = canopycoverSDmax, 
      fill = groups),
    alpha = 0.1
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "green"), name = "fill") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = covermin, ymax = covermax), alpha = 0.1) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = "1 week") +
  theme_bw() + theme(
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_text(size = 10),
    axis.title = element_text(size = 12),
    plot.title = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")
  )
```

[image]